# How to display Individual Custom Fields in a Participants View

Tags: drupal-views

I want to create a View :

- which displays some Individuals Custom Data (e.g. Passport information)
- where Individuals are filtered according to their Participation to an Event (id=20)

I imagine 3 different ways to do that but none of them is working :

1. Create a Contact oriented View and filter via some civicrm_participant fields but the civicrm_participant table (and fields) is not accessible for filtering :[image]
2. Create a Participant oriented View ans add some Individual Custom Fields : but in this case, the custom fields are not populated though I was able to add them :[image]
3. Create a Smart Group based upon the Participants, and then filter the Contact View on this Smart Group, but Views does not seem to consider Smart Groups, but only Static groups

Of course, I checked that my custom field tables are included in settings

Clearing the caches has no effect

How can I solve my problem ? (civicrm 5.6.0 / Drupal 7.60)

Comment: Are you using Views 'Relationships' in adding the custom fields?

Comment: Also are you using Contact Sub-Types or Event Sub-types

Comment: I use Views Relationships (Contributions) in the Participant View to have the Individual Custom Fields (as far as I remember this was Eileen's advice) ... and I have them available in the "Add" or "Filter" fields, but not populated.

Comment: I actually use Individual Sub-Types to distinguish Children and Adults : shoudn't I ? Can it be the cause ? I can, of course, replace sub-types by a Tag or a custom field : would you ?

Comment: I have just removed the sub-type of a test (Participant) Contact : no change

Comment: so the custom fields were not specific to the sub-type?

Comment: No, the custom fields group is related to Individual/All sub-types

Comment: See also my comment, next to JohnFF's there : https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17405/how-to-create-drupal-view-of-participants-with-custom-fields/27476#27476

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what is required by creating a CiviCRM Participants view and using the CiviCRM Participants: Participant's Contact ID as a relationship to bring in contact custom data –

[image]

[image]

Or import the belew view (I've removed custom data so this needs to be added yourself) -

$view = new view();
$view->name = 'individual_and_participant_view';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'civicrm_participant';
$view->human_name = 'Individual and participant view';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Individual and participant view';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '100';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['quantity'] = '9';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'id' => 'id',
  'display_name' => 'display_name',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'id' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'display_name' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
/* Relationship: CiviCRM Participants: Participant's Contact ID */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['contact_id_1']['id'] = 'contact_id_1';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['contact_id_1']['table'] = 'civicrm_participant';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['contact_id_1']['field'] = 'contact_id';
/* Field: CiviCRM Events: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'civicrm_event';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
/* Field: CiviCRM Contacts: Display Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['display_name']['id'] = 'display_name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['display_name']['table'] = 'civicrm_contact';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['display_name']['field'] = 'display_name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['display_name']['link_to_civicrm_contact'] = 0;

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'individual-and-participant-view';

Comment: Thanks a lot, Anil ; I used a Relationship with Contribution's Contact ID instead of Participant's Contact ID : it brought the Contacts custom fields in the play and I could select them but they were not populated. Including Participant's relationship instead works fine. Happy to accept your answer !

Answer (score 3):

We have managed to solve a similar scenario with the help of [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) extension. It's a bit laborious but you can define a (secundary) 'contact view' with the desired fields and then a (primary) 'participant view' with desired participant fields and the 'contact view' as a view field. You need to add a contextual filter on the participant view with the contact ID.

Comment: I am testing this solution, but I have some problems : an AJAX error (https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33132/views-field-view-ajax-error) ; However, Include View seems to work, but is not really satisfactory ; but the AJAX error with Append View seems too important to have it working. Are you aware of that ?